# Laravel: Store Records in Polymorphic One to Many Relationship

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have three tables that related each other throw Polymorphic One to Many Relationship

**Tables**

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

office
    id - integer
    name - string

phones
    id - integer
    name - string
    phones_id - integer
    phones_type - string
```

I want to add phone numbers to `phones` table related to specific user

**user.php**

```
public function phones()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Phone', 'phones');
    }
```

**Phone.php**

```
public function phones()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

**Create.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{route('dashboard.users.store')}}" method="post">
<div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
   <input type="text" name="phone[]" class="form-control">
   <div class="input-group-btn"> 
      <button class="add-more" type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit">save</button>
</form>

<!-- Copy Fields -->
<div class="copy" hidden>
    <div class="control-group input-group">
        <input type="text" name="phone[]" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn"> 
        <button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {             
        $(".add-more").click(function(){ 
            var html = $(".copy").html();
            $(".after-add-more").after(html);
         });
         $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
         $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
   });

</script>
```

I am trying to store records to phones Using this code in `UserController.php`

```
if ($request->phone) {
  $user->phones()->saveMany($request->phone);
}
```

but it gives me an error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given, called
>   in
>   C:\Server\data\htdocs\justice_way\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php
>   on line 264

the `dd($request)` gives me

```
"phone" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "+1 (776) 209-9366"
    1 => "+1 (444) 579-3232"
  ]
```

When i try

```
if ($request->phone) {
     $phone = new Phone;
     $phone->name = $request->phone;
     $user->phones()->save($phone);
}
```

it gives error

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must
>   be of the type array, int given, called in
>   C:\Server\data\htdocs\justice_way\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
>   on line 871

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got it

```
if ($request->phone) {
     foreach ($request->phone as $key => $value) {
        $phone = new Phone;
        $phone->name = $value;
        $nyaba->phones()->save($phone);
   }
}
```